# How to Change Tamplate?

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I added custom attribute to bundle product(For Chocolate Box(Yes/No)); I need change product tamplate(for custom tamplate) if "Yes"  is active!
Help me please!

Controller

```
class Chocolate_Box_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

        public function indexAction()
        {
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();
        }
}
```

config.xml

```
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <chocolatebox>
                <file>chocolatebox.xml</file>
            </chocolatebox>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

layout

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/chocolatebox/chocolatebox.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><stylesheet>chocolatebox/css/style.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>chocolatebox/chocolatebox.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways. In your case your layout reference is incorrect (should be `reference="root"`).

### From the controller:

```
class Chocolate_Box_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');
    }
}
```

### From the layout:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```

Comment: It doesn`t help me! I think I need to use _beforeToHtml() method

Comment: Template should be set in constructor. What other modules do you have installed?